# Generalise a method

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

I got this method

```
public static Integer addCollectionElements(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum).intValue();
}
```

which I would like to generalise to any class that implements the method sum (e.g. Float).

Is it possible to achieve this by using Java Generics?

Comment: No, it isn't.  Sorry.

Comment: @khelwood It's a static method, so the superclass isn't relevant.

Comment: @shmosel Good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) base class doesn't have a `sum` method, so you can't do this directly. What you could do, however, is call `doubleValue()` on each `Number` you receive, and sum them as a doubles:

```
public static double addCollectionElements(List<? extends Number> list){
    return list.stream().mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).sum();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Double::sum`?

Comment: @shmosel Good point, thanks - I'll edit that in. Definitely more elegant than reimplementing it myself with `a+b`.

Comment: This will _usually_ work, but be careful if you want to use this in a context where you could be dealing with a `List<Long>`. If you store a number larger than +/-2^52 in a double, you'll start losing precision, where a long can store numbers up to +/-2^63.

Comment: You don’t even need Double::sum or the reduce method at all.  DoubleStream has its own [sum()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--) method.

Comment: You could even do `Collection<? extends Number>`.

Comment: @4castle I was trying to keep the signature as close to the OP's as possible, but you're right, this will work with any collection.

Answer (score 4):

`Integer.sum()` is just a static method which can be used as a `BinaryOperator`. There is no way to make it "generic for objects that have a method `sum`". 
What you can do is add two more arguments to the method, where you provide your own `sum` function and an initial value - zero in your case. An extreme example would be this:

```
public static <T extends Number> T addCollectionElements(List<T> list, T initialValue, BinaryOperator<T> sumFunction){
    return list.stream().reduce(initialValue, sumFunction);
}
```

Invocation would look like this:

```
addCollectionElements(list, 0, Integer::sum);
```

But I do not believe you would gain anything by doing this.